# Get the next two proceeding elements from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have a javascript array
 And i wish to get the next preceeding two elements using a function and slice.
I'm not getting the result. Is there any way to go around this?

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

 function get(arr){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
       console.log(arr.slice(i, 3))
    }}


// Now when I call the function

    get(arr)

// Funny output

[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3]
[3]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the index of `i` and the next two numbers in the array? For example, `[1,2,3]`, then `[2,3,4]` then `[3,4,5]`, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the index instead of the length with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> arr.slice([begin[, end]])
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **`end` Optional**
>
> Zero-based index before which to end extraction. `slice` extracts up to but not including end.
>
> For example, `slice(1,4)` extracts the second element through the fourth element (elements indexed 1, 2, and 3).
>
> A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence. `slice(2,-1)` extracts the third element through the second-to-last element in the sequence.
>
> If `end` is omitted, `slice` extracts through the end of the sequence (`arr.length`).
>
> If `end` is greater than the length of the sequence, `slice` extracts through to the end of the sequence (`arr.length`).

```js
function get(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr.slice(i, i + 3));
    }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

get(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `slice()` is end index.  So what you're saying is give me all elements from `i` to index 3 (not-inclusive).

What you should be saying is `slice(i, i+3)`

Answer (score 0):

`slice(i, 3)` basically means you want a new array with elements between the index before index `i` and index `3`. You can just use a simple `for loop` instead to return the proceeding two elements of each element like this:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

function get(x){
 for (i = 0; i < x.length - 2; i++){   
   console.log("The proceeding two elements of " + x[i] + " is " + x[i+1] + " and " + x[i+2]);
  }
}
 
 get(arr);
```

**N.B.** The `- 2` in the for loop's `x.length - 2` is to prevent returning an undefined result since the last two elements won't have two proceeding elements.

---

Or if you prefer using `slice()`, you can do this:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

function get(x){
  for (i = 0; i < x.length - 2; i++){   
    console.log(x.slice(i, i+3));
  }
}

get(arr);
```

Again, the `- 2` in the for loop's `x.length - 2` is to prevent returning an undefined result or an incomplete result since the last two elements won't have two proceeding elements.

Comment: @FogangRodriq Glad I could help man. Cheers and happy new years!!

Comment: Same to you Enjoy!! :)